# C, free function acts weirdly. why?

Tags: c

i wrote a code for generic lists. among its functions, it has a freelist, createlist and copylist. 
while freeing a list created by createlist function it all works fine, but when trying to free a list created by copylist function the program crashes, i checked the values when debugging and I still see no reason for this to happen.
this is what I've got:

```
void listDestroy(List list)
{
    if(list==NULL) return;
    listClear(list);
    free(list); //<-crashes here when freeing copied lists.
    list=NULL;
    return;
}

int main()
{
    List list = listCreate(copyString,freeString);
    List copied = listCopy(list);
    listDestroy(list);
    listDestroy(copied);
    printf("success");
    return 0;
}

List listCreate(CopyListElement copyElement, FreeListElement freeElement)
{
    if(!copyElement || !freeElement) return NULL;
    List newlist=malloc(sizeof(*newlist));
    if(newlist==NULL) return NULL;
    newlist->copy = copyElement;
    newlist->free= freeElement;
    newlist->nodes=NULL;
    newlist->iterator=NULL;
    return newlist;
}


Node *copynode(Node *node, CopyListElement copyElement)
{
    if(node==NULL) return NULL;
    Node *newnode=malloc(sizeof(newnode));
    if(newnode==NULL) return NULL;
    newnode->next=node->next;
    newnode->element=copyElement(node->element);
    return newnode;
}

List listCopy(List list)
{
    if(!list) return NULL;
    List newlist=malloc(sizeof(newlist));
    if(newlist==NULL) return NULL;
    newlist->copy = list->copy;
    newlist->free= list->free;
    if(list->nodes!=NULL)
    {
        Node *firstlink=copynode(list->nodes, newlist->copy);
        newlist->nodes=firstlink;
        newlist->iterator=firstlink;
        Node *newpointer=firstlink;
        Node *listPointer=list->nodes->next;
        while(listPointer!=NULL)
        {
            Node *newlink=copynode(listPointer, newlist->copy);
            newpointer->next=newlink;
            if(listPointer==list->iterator)
            {
                newlist->iterator=newlink;
            }
            listPointer=listPointer->next;
            newpointer=newpointer->next;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        newlist->iterator=NULL;
        newlist->nodes=NULL;
    }
    return newlist;
}
```

Now, while debugging the values for both list and copied (in main) show the same, but while freeing list works, free copied causes a crash.
why?

Comment: You are passing around by value parameters everywhere, that seems to be the source of your problems.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ There must be a `typedef struct whatever *List`, otherwise `List newlist=malloc(sizeof(*newlist));` would not compile.

Comment: C is not Java. In C, it is *not* a good idea to do a `typedef struct whatever* Type` to mimic Java types. Since you can declare both variables *containing* objects and pointers *to* objects, it's important for readers to know which one is used where. And that one extra `*` is easier to type than the `typedef`.

Comment: List is a pointer to a struct, I guess I should have added the struct as well for better understanding

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For starters:

In `listCopy()` this

```
List newlist=malloc(sizeof(newlist));
```

should be

```
List newlist=malloc(sizeof(*newlist));
```

or nicer:

```
List newlist = malloc(sizeof *newlist);
```

---

Same in `copynode()` for this line:

```
Node *newnode=malloc(sizeof(newnode));
```

which should be

```
Node * newnode = malloc(sizeof *newnode);
```

---

And btw, in `listDestroy()` this line:

```
list=NULL;
```

is useless, as `list` is copy to what had been given as parameter on the call to `listDestroy()`.

Comment: @Jonathan: You are welcome. If you feel this answers your question you are free to mark this answer as such by clicking its check-mark. This would also mark your question as answered.

Answer (score 0):

`List` is presumably a pointer to something.

The second line of `listCopy()` is

```
List newlist=malloc(sizeof(newlist));
```

which is incorrect, and will cause later code to exhibit undefined behaviour.

I would not exclude the possibility of other errors in the code.

Comment: If `List` wouln't be a pointer-type the code would not compile ...

Comment: @alk The original question was tagged both C and C++. If `List` is a pointer type, the code must be C, but C++ leaves open the possibility for other types that can be initialised using a `void *`. I agree that it's almost certain that `List` is a pointer type, but we have no way of actually *knowing* that.

Comment: @hvh: Ahok, I missed the C++ tag.

Comment: I only saw the post tagged as C.   The only reason I commented about `List` being a pointer type is that the code sample was obviously not complete.